# cms_page_prepare_save not working

Tags: event-observer, cms, ce-1.9.2.2

I am trying to observe the event `cms_page_prepare_save` but it is now working.

Code in **config.xml**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Custom_Test>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Test>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <test>
            <rewrite>
                <processor_requestid>Custom_Test_Helper_Processor_Requestid</processor_requestid>
            </rewrite>
        </test>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <test>
            <rewrite>
                <processor>Custom_Test_Model_Processor</processor>
            </rewrite>
            <rewrite>
                <observer>Custom_Test_Model_Observer</observer>
            </rewrite>
        </test>
    </models>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <custom_test>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>test/processor</class>
                    <method>serveResponse</method>
                </custom_test>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        <cms_page_render>
            <observers>
                <custom_test_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Custom_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addCustomData</method>
                </custom_test_observer>
            </observers>
        </cms_page_render>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Above two event and observers are working fine, but below is not working at all.

```
<events>
   <cms_page_prepare_save>
    <observers>
       <Custom_Test_Model_Observer>
           <type>singleton</type>
           <class>test/observer</class>
           <method>saveCmsPageObserve</method>
           </Custom_Test_Model_Observer>
       </observers>
  </cms_page_prepare_save>
</events>
```

Tried in `<admin>`, `<adminhtml>` and `<global>` tags.

`class Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_PageController` is over written, does this have something to do with the issue.
Or is there any other issue?

Comment: You need to add your code in `<adminhtml>` tag firstly. Can you add the code of your observer `test/observer` ?

Comment: can you please share config.xml and what is observer class  for cms_page_prepare_save event?

Comment: @AmitBera Updated the question with config.xml code

Comment: @TaKe_Da_ShAkEr tried in <adminhtml> tag as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code in `config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Custom_Test>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Test>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <test>
            <rewrite>
                <processor_requestid>Custom_Test_Helper_Processor_Requestid</processor_requestid>
            </rewrite>
        </test>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <test>
            <rewrite>
                <processor>Custom_Test_Model_Processor</processor>
            </rewrite>
            <rewrite>
                <observer>Custom_Test_Model_Observer</observer>
            </rewrite>
        </test>
    </models>
    <events>
        <cms_page_prepare_save>
            <observers>
                <custom_test_cms_page_prepare>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Custom_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveCmsPageObserve</method>
                </custom_test_cms_page_prepare>
            </observers>
        </cms_page_prepare_save>
    </events>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <custom_test>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>test/processor</class>
                    <method>serveResponse</method>
                </custom_test>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        <cms_page_render>
            <observers>
                <custom_test_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Custom_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addCustomData</method>
                </custom_test_observer>
            </observers>
        </cms_page_render>
    </events>
</frontend>
```